# How to show all remote branches in GitExtensions?

Tags: git, git-extensions

When I run `git remote -v` on my repository, two remotes are shown: **hub** (me) and **origin**.

My problem is relatively simple: I want GitExtensions to display branches from both remotes in the diagram in the center of the screen. As of right now, it's only showing branches from **origin**.

My git repository is in precisely the state I want it to be in. In other words, `git branch -r` is showing all branches for both myself and origin. The issue is that GitExtensions isn't showing branches from **hub** in its colored diagram in the center of the screen that shows how branches and commits interact.

If this is relevant, in the View tab at the top of the screen, I have selected "Show all branches" and "Show remote branches".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is insufficient information to tell what is wrong with your configuration. Git logs/screenshots etc would help us in helping you.
You're also more likely get help at our Gitter channel (https://gitter.im/gitextensions/gitextensions) or GitHub repo (https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "Branches" in the left branch menu and click on "Expand all". This will show all remotes in the GUI.

Comment: Ok it's a yer old, and slightly incorrect. But thanks, this helped.
I right clicked on "Remotes" rather than "Branches" and it showed the one I'd recently created, that for some reason didnt show in the checkout list

Comment: Helped me too. 
Don't forget to do a git pull if someone else created the branch to see it in the list.

Answer (score -3):

```
git branch -a
```

this will show you all the branches,

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of that command, and it has almost nothing to do with the question. I already said that all of the necessary branches are pulled down and my git repository is in the correct state.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.